# Advice on how to debug python code using Pycharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I am a relatively new python user, and wanted advice on how best to debug my code.

Currently, I have a script (main.py), that I run in debug mode using PyCharm. This file is quite short, as most of my functions are contained within another module I have written (i.e. functionsmodule.py). If I put breakpoints in the function I want to modify in functionsmodule.py, this works quite well - then I can explore the variables available inside this function.

However, if I update the function in 'functionsmodule.py', save the file, then reload using importlib.reload, the breakpoints don't seem to be recognised anymore. I then have to rerun the whole of main.py to get to the breakpoint again.

Is there a better solution to this? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify a breakpoint in the code directly using the built-in `breakpoint()`function, which might help in a case like this.

See [PEP-553](https://peps.python.org/pep-0553/) for more details.